# Recursive allocation to a vector of return type vector itself

Tags: c++, vector, return

I wished to recieve a vector which contained the data of node within the range of(min,max)

but gives an error:

```
no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back [with _Tp=int, _Alloc=std::allocator<int>]" matches the argument listC/C++(304)
ex1.cpp(116, 12): argument types are: (std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>)
ex1.cpp(116, 12): object type is: std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>
```

```
vector<int> rangeBWVec(binaryTreeNode<int>* root,int min, int max){
    
    vector<int> re;
    if(root==NULL){

        return re;
    }
    if(root->data>=min)
    {
        re.push_back(rangeBWVec(root->left,min,max));
    }

    if(root->data>=min && root->data<=max)
        re.push_back(root->data);

    if(root->data<=max)
    {
       re.push_back(rangeBWVec(root->right,min,max));
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`push_back` appends a single item, if you want to copy all the items from another container into this one then you need to use `insert` method. However there is no need to bother with merging containers, just pass accumulating vector by reference. This will not only simplify the code, but also reduce amount of memory allocations.

```
void rangeBWVec
(
    binaryTreeNode<int> const * const p_node
,   int const min
,   int const max
,   vector<int> & accum
)
{
    if (p_node)
    {
        if (min <= p_node->data)
        {
            rangeBWVec(p_node->left, min, max, accum));
        }
        if ((min <= p_node->data) and (p_node->data <= max))
        {
            accum.emplace_back(p_node->data);
        }
        if (p_node->data <= max)
        {
            rangeBWVec(p_node->right, min, max, accum);
        }
    }
}
```